# WFRP 2e Weapon and Armour craftsmanship?

Tags: wfrp-2e

I've recently entered a WFRP 2nd Edition campaign. I'm having a hard time finding price and availability modifiers for Good and Best craftsmanship weapons and armor.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [core rulebook](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/62847/Warhammer-Fantasy-Roleplay-2nd-Edition-Core-Rulebook?affiliate_id=188022), the Craftsmanship modifiers for Cost and Availability are found on page 105, first column, below "Slang in the Old World." Details of game effects are found on page 107 in the top callout.

### Update

Craftmanship Cost and Availability is also noted in [*Old World Armoury*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/63109/Warhammer-Fantasy-Roleplay-2nd-Edition-Old-World-Armoury?affiliate_id=188022) on page 5. Game effects are called out in **Weapon Craftmanship** on page 28.